# Java - Calling functions in extended classes through an object array

Tags: java, arrays, function, class, extends

I've got an array of objects, some of which use an extended version which contains a function not available in the base class. How can I call that function through the array when the array is defined by the base class?

Example

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[10];

shapes[0] = new Circle(10) //10 == radius, only exists in circle class which extends Shape

shapes[0].getRadius(); //Gives me a compilation error as getRadius() doesn't exist in the      
Shape class, only in the extended Circle class. Is there a way around this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shape` class does not contain the method `getRadius` and hence without casting the object of `Shape` to `Circle`, the method will not be visible. So you should use this:

```
((Circle)shapes[0]).getRadius();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (shapes[0] instanceof Circle) 
       ((Circle)shapes[0]).getRadius();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your object is of a given subclass, use cast:

```
((Circle)shapes[0]).getRadius();
```