# Array to store objects of two different classes?

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner in java and programming in general.Basically, I am wondering whether if it is possible to store objects of different classes in the same array. For example, instead of create 2 seperate arrays like this:

```
//AssembledPart is subclass of Part
Part[] part = new Part[4];
    part[0] = new Part("p101", "Crank", 218, 12.20);
    part[1] = new Part("p102", "Pedal", 320, 14.30);
    part[2] = new Part("p103", "Handlebar", 120, 35.50);
    part[3] = new Part("p104", "Stem", 90, 20.00);

    AssembledPart[] asPart = new AssembledPart[2];
    asPart[0] = new AssembledPart("p183", "Crank-Pedal", 80, 3.50, part[0], part[1]);
    asPart[1] = new AssembledPart("p184", "Handlebar-Stem", 30, 1.50, part[2], part[3]);
```

Is there any other way to combine them in to just one array.If there is a way, how can I do it.

Comment: You could combined them (casting as the parent class) but once in your array, there would be no quick way to determine which class each element is

Comment: You could check out the Collections :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: It looks like you are using [the Composite design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `AssembledPart` is a subclass of `Part` (as you indicated in the comments), then what you're asking is trivial. Subclasses can always be assigned to their parent classes, so all you need to do is:

```
Part[] part = new Part[6];
part[0] = new Part("p101", "Crank", 218, 12.20);
part[1] = new Part("p102", "Pedal", 320, 14.30);
part[2] = new Part("p103", "Handlebar", 120, 35.50);
part[3] = new Part("p104", "Stem", 90, 20.00);
part[4] = new AssembledPart("p183", "Crank-Pedal", 80, 3.50, part[0], part[1]);
part[5] = new AssembledPart("p184", "Handlebar-Stem", 30, 1.50, part[2], part[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the official documentation [Java Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html):

> An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of
>   a **single type**...

The short answer is that you cannot use different classes.

However, the trick here is that you can use object orientation so that an array is created for a more generic class which allows for subclasses to be set in the array.

You mentioned that `AssembledPart` is a subclass of `Part`, and that means you are allowed to set a `AssembledPart` object into a `Part` array. Like this:

```
    Part[] yourArray = new Part[2];
    yourArray[0] = new Part();
    yourArray[1] = new AssembledPart();
```

This very same concept will work not only when using collections but in many other object usage, in virtually all object oriented languages.

I suggest you to read more in [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html), will clear your mind in some of this concepts =).

Comment: Why the downvote? Can you please point out what the answer is missing?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have different objects in the same array. When you create an object array, you specify a certain object to be put into that array. You'll have to create different object arrays for different classes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that  Assembled Part is subclass of Part. It is still not possible?

Comment: @TamLam then it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Your question may have been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285130/java-calling-functions-in-extended-classes-through-an-object-array

Answer (score 1):

You can create an interface IPart and implement that in both Part and AssembledPart. that way you can create an array of that interface and use that array to store both Part and AssembledPart object there.

```
interface IPart {
}

class Part implements IPart {
}

class AssembledPart implements IPart {
}
// in code you can do following...
IPart[] parts = new IPart[2];
parts[0] = new Part(...);
parts[1] = new AssembledPart(...);
```

you can also do it by extending the AssembledPart

```
 class Part {
 }
 class AssembledPart extends Part{
 }
 // in code..
 Part[] parts = new Part[2];
 parts[0] = new Part(...);
 parts[1] = new AssembledPart(...);
```

another way you can do it by using array of Object

```
 Object[] parts = new Object[2];
 parts[0] = new Part(...);
 parts[1] = new AssembledPart(...);
```

but you need to understand why you want to merge two array and how you want to merge it.

fyi, at some point you may need to check what kind of object you have in the array. you can do it by using.

```
  if(parts[0] instance of AssembledPart) {
     // do something.
  }
```

Comment: I tried to use Objects[] array before. It does store my objects however, I couldn't call methods of the objects. Does that mean if I store Assembled Part object in a Part[] array, I will not be able to call their (Assembled Part objects) methods?

Comment: you can call the AssembledPart objects method. but you need to type cast it first. like ((AssembledPart)array[0]).someAssembledPartMethod();